# Intelligent linear indexing ordered tuples of N items from 1:M

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, combinatorics

I'm looking to index the M choose N tuples using a linear index.  Some time ago I wrote the code for M choose 2 as some pair indexing function:

```
   function K=pairidx( i, j)
      if(i>j)
        swap(i,j);
      K=j-(i+1) +   (i)*(2*M-1)-i*(i-1)/2;
   end
```

What I need now is the generalization of this to M choose N.  Ideally, I would have an invertible function where I can convert from index K to some tuple (K_1, K_2,...,K_N). So far I've been doing a brute force method where for N=3 I wrote the following function but I hope this isn't best that one can do.

```
function lookup=tripletable()
d=nchoosek(M,N);
idx=1;
lookup=zeros(d,3);
for i=1:M
     for j=i+1:M
         for k=j+1:M
             lookup(idx,:)=[i,j,k];
             idx=idx+1;
         end
     end
end
```

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding you, you can use the builtin function [c = nchoosek(v,k)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html), where v is a vector of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jerad commented, you could use `nchoosek(v,k)` to generate the entire list of combinations and then let Matlab match your (sorted) combination to any of the rows. However, this would require the entire list to be generated which might be quite large if M and N get bigger.

You could use the following code to get a combination by index. It calculates the number of possible combinations and checks if the index you've given is in that range. It then iteratively goes on to determine all elements

```
function combination=getCombinationByIndex(v,K,N)
M=size(v,2);
k=K;
l=0;
combination=zeros(1,N);
for i=1:N
    %determine combination(i)
    while(true)
        l=l+1;
        C=nchoosek(M-l,N-i);         
        if(k>C)
            k=k-C;
        else
            combination(i) = v(l);
            break;
        end
    end
end
```

The reverse operation is similar: just sort your combination and go over the elements, checking if your current combination is in that range.

EDIT: the reverse operation as provided by topic starter and expanded to allow arbitrary sets of elements:

```
function k=getIndexByCombination(v,combo) 
M=length(v);
v=sort(v);
combo=sort(combo); 
N=length(combo); 
l=0; 
%k is the index 
k=1; 
for i=1:N
    while(true)
        l=l+1;    
        if(combo(i)==v(l))
            break;
        else
            C=nchoosek(M-l,N-i);
            k=k+C;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I must admit I wasn't aware of the vector capabilities of nchoosek(v,k) but your solution is quite elegant and has impressive speed even for large M.  Only change is that the l=l+1 statement should go before evaluating C i.e.:
`l=l+1;
 C=nchoosek(M-l,N-i);        
`
Thank you

Comment: I'll fix your comment but then l should start at 0 as well (for v(1) to ever be selected)

Comment: The reverse operation, in case anyone else visits this thread:

`function k=getIndexByCombination(combo,M)`
`combo=sort(combo);`
`N=length(combo);`
`l=0;`
`%k is the index`
`k=1;`
`for i=1:N`
`   while(true)`
`         l=l+1;`
`         C=nchoosek(M-l,N-i);`
`         if(combo(i)==l)`
`            break;`
`         else`
`            k=k+C;`
`          end`
`      end`
`    end`